# How to divide footer in column wise along with footer contents?

Tags: angular-material

I'm setting footer with headings title as About, contact us, popular searches, Blogs. I want to display the contents below footer title but its not working. I'm getting the output like contents are getting displayed next to footer title.

I tried to use the grid system but no result as of now.

```
Contact us            Services          Blogs     

no:12, 8th cross,     Find doctors       Twitter
Rajajinagar,          Find hospitals     Facebook
Bangalore.
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" row Height="4:0.8" class="list"> 
  <mat-grid-tile >Contact Us <h3>Contact us</h3> </mat-grid-tile> 
  <mat-grid-tile>Services</mat-grid-tile> 
  <mat-grid-tile>About Us</mat-grid-tile> 
  <mat-grid-tile>Popular Searches</mat-grid-tile> 
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: <mat-grid-list cols="4" row Height="4:0.8" class="list">
            <mat-grid-tile >Contact Us
<h3>Contact us</h3>
</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Services</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>About Us</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Popular Searches</mat-grid-tile>
          </mat-grid-list>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mat-grid-tile-header` in order to define the title (e.g. Contact Us, Services etc), then define the content below this - but still within `mat-grid-tile`

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" row Height="4:0.8" class="list"> 
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile-header>
      <h3>Contact us</h3>
    </mat-grid-tile-header>
    no:12, 8th cross,<br/>
    Rajajinagar,<br/>
    Bangalore.
  </mat-grid-tile> 
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile-header>
      <h3>Services</h3>
    </mat-grid-tile-header>
    Find doctors<br/>
    Find hospitals
  </mat-grid-tile> 
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile-header>
      <h3>Blogs</h3>
    </mat-grid-tile-header>  
    Twitter<br/>
    Facebook
  </mat-grid-tile> 
</mat-grid-list>
```

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6faz7?file=app/grid-list-dynamic-example.ts) for a working demo.